# HTML page moves content around when zooming or resizing page

Tags: html, css, resize

Every time I resize my page all the content will move to fit. However I have another page that uses the same CSS style and it does not move. Here is my code for the page:

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#ccefff;
}

footer{
    width: 100%;

}

button{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
}
.wrapper:after{
    content: "";
    display:block;
}
.wrapper:after{
    height: 350px;
}

h1{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: light;
    color: white;
    text-align: middle;

}
input[type=text]{
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px groove #ccc;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px groove #555;
}

fieldset{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px ;
    width= 100%;
    height= 900px;
    background-image:url("PICTURE");
    background-size: cover;
}

.text_bot_01{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: right;

}

.partner01
{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body> 
<center>
<div class = wrapper>


<h1>Welcome to priority health for you - Your health is our priority </h1>
<p>Need a quote? Simply type your name below and press "Get a quote" </p>
<br>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="name01" placeholder="Please enter your first name ">
<button type="submit">Get a quote</button>
</form>

<p>Once you fill in the details, one of the team will contact you shortly </p>
</center>

<div class="text_bot_01">

<img src="PICTURE" align=right class="partner01" />

</fieldset>
<br>
<footer> <center>Copyright 2016 &#169; Priority health for you </center></footer>
</html>
```

I have a wrapper but it seems every time I change something the entire layout will change.

Comment: PHP is server-side code, you need to research about that if you are not aware.   In other words, it has nothing to do with how the browser renders the page.  This is strictly an HTML/CSS question.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Devon